# compare the row values to get the value from other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
    qtr         value
0   2008Q2  485000000.000
1   2008Q2  485000000.000
2   2008Q2  485000000.000
3   2008Q2  485000000.000
4   2008Q2  12399000000.000
5   2008Q4  181000000.000
6   2009Q2  179000000.000
7   2009Q3  359200000.000
8   2009Q3  3221289753.000
0   2008Q2  485000000.000
1   2008Q2  485000000.000
2   2008Q2  485000000.000
3   2008Q2  485000000.000
4   2008Q2  12399000000.000
5   2008Q4  181000000.000
6   2009Q2  179000000.000
```

What I want to do is compare the two subsequent rows of `qtr` and get value from `value`.

However I got stuck on this:

`df['date'].dt.to_period('Q').apply(lambda x : 'true' if df['date'].dt.to_period('Q').shift(1) >x else 'false' )`

I get following `ValueError`

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

if 2009Q3 > 2009Q2, then I want result from 2009Q3
else value from 2009Q2 from corresponding row

example

comparing row 1 and row 2

want '485000000.000' in the third column for both rows

now comparing row 6 and row 7, I want '359200000.000' in the sixth row (from the top)

Following code gives me a solution

```
df['qtr'] =df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')
df['sQtr']=df['date'].dt.to_period('Q').shift(1)
df=df.sort_values(by='qtr', ascending=True)

df[['qtr', 'value', 'sQtr']]
df.loc[df['qtr'] > df['sQtr']]
```

That is not what I want, I want all rows appearing. The above syntax only shows `True` values

**SOLUTION** that worked for me is to create list of dictionaries (because pd.to_dict()) wont accept duplicate keys). A list will.

```
from datequarter import DateQuarter


dates=[]
for i in allData:
     ##allData is converted list of Dictionaries, each row represent a dictionary. use # pd.to_dict()

    for j in range(0, len(i['all'])-1):
        
        qtr= DateQuarter.from_date(i['all'][j]['date']) ## Extract the quarter for the date under consideration
        next_qtr= DateQuarter.from_date(i['all'][j+1]['date'])
        if qtr < next_qtr: ## check the quarter is lower than the  previous one. 
            print(qtr,'ttt' ,next_qtr, next_qtr-qtr)
           
        
        
        
    break
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Henry, added some clarification.

Comment: There’s a lot of duplicates in your example @Ipt, I see only 6 unique rows. Is that normal ? Do you want to compare all pairs of rows ? Only those that are together ?

Comment: @Cimbali I did not show entire dataset, it has over 37 columns.

Comment: That’s OK @Ipt, I thought I might have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

try:

```
c1=df[df['qtr'].eq(pd.Period('2009Q3'))]
c2=df[df['qtr'].eq(pd.Period('2009Q2'))]
res=c2['value'].mask(c1['value'].values>c2['value'].values,c1['value'].values)
df['newval']=df['value']
df.loc[res.index,'newval']=res.values
```

output of `df`:

```
    qtr     value           newval
0   2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
1   2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
2   2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
3   2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
4   2008Q2  1.239900e+10    1.239900e+10
5   2008Q4  1.810000e+08    1.810000e+08
6   2009Q2  1.790000e+08    3.592000e+08
7   2009Q3  3.592000e+08    3.592000e+08
8   2009Q3  3.221290e+09    3.221290e+09
9   2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
10  2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
11  2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
12  2008Q2  4.850000e+08    4.850000e+08
13  2008Q2  1.239900e+10    1.239900e+10
14  2008Q4  1.810000e+08    1.810000e+08
15  2009Q2  1.790000e+08    3.221290e+09
```

Comment: Actually working with dictionary makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want the original shape with the same value for each group, you should use `GroupBy`+ `transform`. Here the transform you want is applying `max`.

I’m not entirely sure which grouping you need, if I understood well it’s any 2 lines next to each other ?

In that case, let’s create groups that are the same for any 2 consecutive rows, e.g. `np.arange(0, len(df)) // 2` and do the grouping:

```
>>> df['max row pair'] = df['value'].groupby(np.arange(0, len(df)) // 2).transform('max')
>>> df
      qtr         value  max row pair
0  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  4.850000e+08
1  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  4.850000e+08
2  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  4.850000e+08
3  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  4.850000e+08
4  2008Q2  1.239900e+10  1.239900e+10
5  2008Q4  1.810000e+08  1.239900e+10
6  2009Q2  1.790000e+08  3.592000e+08
7  2009Q3  3.592000e+08  3.592000e+08
8  2009Q3  3.221290e+09  3.221290e+09
0  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  3.221290e+09
1  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  4.850000e+08
2  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  4.850000e+08
3  2008Q2  4.850000e+08  1.239900e+10
4  2008Q2  1.239900e+10  1.239900e+10
5  2008Q4  1.810000e+08  1.810000e+08
6  2009Q2  1.790000e+08  1.810000e+08
```

Comment: Well Actually, I had to convert the dataframe into a dictionary, and then iterate over for loop.